# ROC_AUC_SCORE is different while calculating using predict() vs predict_proba() in Random Forest

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

Both predict() vs predict_proba() gives different roc_auc_score in Random Forest.

I understand that predict_proba() gives probabilities such as in case of Binary Classification it will gives two probabilities corresponding both classes.
predict() gives class it predicted.

```
    #Using predict_proba()
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=39)
    rf.fit(X_train[['Cabin_mapped', 'Sex']], y_train)

    #make predictions on train and test set
    pred_train = rf.predict_proba(X_train[['Cabin_mapped', 'Sex']])
    pred_test = rf.predict_proba(X_test[['Cabin_mapped', 'Sex']].fillna(0))

    print('Train set')
    print('Random Forests using predict roc-auc: {}'.format(roc_auc_score (y_train, pred_train)))

    print('Test set')
    print('Random Forests using predict roc-auc: {}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_test, pred_test)))

   #using predict()

   pred_train = rf.predict(X_train[['Cabin_reduced', 'Sex']])
   pred_test = rf.predict(X_test[['Cabin_reduced', 'Sex']])

   print('Train set')
   print('Random Forests using predict roc-auc: {}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_train, pred_train)))
   print('Test set')
   print('Random Forests using predict roc-auc: {}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_test, pred_test)))
```

Train set Random Forests using predict_proba roc-auc: 0.8199550985878832

Test set Random Forests using preditc_proba roc-auc: 0.8332142857142857

Train set Random Forests using predict roc-auc: 0.7779440793041364

Test set Random Forests using predict roc-auc: 0.7686904761904761

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said, the `predict` function returns the prediction as `True`/`False` value, whereas `proba` function returns probabilities, values between one and zero 
and this is the reason for the difference.

AUC means "area under the curve" which is indeed different if the curve is a 0/1 step function or a curve made of continuous values.

Let's imagine you have only one example, it should be classified as `False`. If your classifier yields the probability of 0.7, the ROC-AUC value is 1.0-0.7=0.3. If you used `predict`, the prediction will be `True` = 1.0, so the ROC-AUC will be 1.0-1.0=0.0.

Comment: Found exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: what about different F1 results?

Comment: That last paragraph is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Predict` returns the predicted value.

`Predict_proba` returns the probabilities of the predicted values.