# Difference between predict vs predict_proba in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, prediction

Suppose I have created a model, and my target variable is either `0`, `1` or `2`.  It seems that if I use `predict`, the answer is either of 0, or 1 or 2. But if I use `predict_proba`, I get a row with 3 cols for each row as follows, for example

```
   model = ... Classifier       # It could be any classifier
   m1 = model.predict(mytest)
   m2= model.predict_proba(mytest)

   # Now suppose  m1[3] = [0.6, 0.2, 0.2]
```

Suppose I use both predict and `predict_proba`.  If in index 3, I get the above result with the result of `predict_proba`, in index 3 of the result of predict I should see 0. Is this the case? I am trying to understand how using both `predict` and `predict_proba` on the same model relate to each other.

Comment: Please, instead of "*suppose*", post an actual code example of using both `predict` and `predict_proba`, so we can ground the discussion in an actual (and not hypothetical) case.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my question

Comment: Still unclear. `m1` is supposed to contain single numbers (classes), while here you show it as if containing probabilities. Please, take your time, focus, and update/clarify the question accordingly (the idea was to get rid of "*suppose*", by showing an actual example of **both** `predict` and `predict_proba` on the **same** test sample and focus the question on this, but you haven't done so).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397128/roc-auc-score-is-different-while-calculating-using-predict-vs-predict-proba

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- **`predict()`** is used to predict the *actual class* (in your case one of `0`, `1`, or `2`).
- **`predict_proba()`** is used to predict the *class probabilities*

---

From the example output that you shared,

- `predict()` would output class `0` since the class probability for `0` is 0.6.
- `[0.6, 0.2, 0.2]` is the output of `predict_proba` that simply denotes that the class probability for classes `0`, `1`, and `2` are `0.6`, `0.2`, and `0.2` respectively.

---

Now as the documentation mentions for `predict_proba`, the resulting array is ordered based on the labels you've been using:

> The returned estimates for all classes are ordered by the label of
> classes.

Therefore, in your case where your class labels are `[0, 1, 2]`, the corresponding output of `predict_proba` will contain the corresponding probabilities. `0.6` is the probability of the instance to be classified as `0` and `0.2` are the probabilities that the instance is categorised as `1` and `2` respectively.

---

For a more comprehensive explanation, refer to the article [What is the difference between predict() and predict_proba() in scikit-learn](https://towardsdatascience.com/predict-vs-predict-proba-scikit-learn-bdc45daa5972) on TDS.

Comment: @Giorgos, please note my question is regarding the relationship between exact indexes of these two. Also, I wonder if there is a typo in  your answer, there are two ones as output of predict()