# Soft-voting ML algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning

How can I print the probability for each class when I am using the soft-voting classifier?

I have tried to print the probability for each class by soft-voting using Python, but I couldn't.

Comment: Are you using scikit-learn?

Comment: yes I using scikit-learn

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please *clarify in the question* (not in the comments) - which soft classifier from which library (and edit also the tags accordingly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using scikit-learn you can use [predict_proba](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.predict_proba)

```py
pred_proba = eclf.predict_proba(X)
```

Here `eclf` is your Voting classifier and will return `Weighted average probability for each class per sample.`

`pred_proba[0]` will contain list of probabilities per class for first sample, and `pred_proba[1]` will contain list of probabilites per class for second sample and so on..

Comment: Here is difference between [predict and predict_proba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184906/difference-between-predict-vs-predict-proba-in-scikit-learn) which might be helpful